# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable, sys.argv()

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I'm working on a python script to run in Terminal that encodes and decodes a message. I'm using sys.argv() to check whether the user wants to encode it or decode it, but it's saying that 'list' object is not callable?

```
    #encode or decode
    enorde = 0
    for arg in sys.argv(): #error here
        if enorde == 0:
            if arg == 'encode':
                encode()
            elif arg == 'decode':
                decode()
            else:
                print("Unknown argument: ",arg)
            enorde = enorde + 1
        else:
            break
```

And terminal:

```
  File "./secmsg.py", line 117, in <module>
    startup()
  File "./secmsg.py", line 38, in startup
    for arg in sys.argv():
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Any reasons?

Comment: `argv` isn't a function, it's a list. Just do `for arg in sys.argv:`.

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list, not a function. Just omit the `()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, completely didn't realize sys.argv didn't use parentheses!